# Browser Language Preference Statistics by Country

Tags: browsers, statistics

I'm wondering which languages are most popular with internet users in countries around the world.

My initial research found browser usage statistics by country, but nothing about proportional language preference.

Are there any such resources?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the country itself and researching its most commonly spoken languages. I would advise against using the country's official language(s) because they are not always accurate to the population.

Here's a great resource to get you started: [World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/)

Comment: That's right! Send him to the CIA!! That won't hurt much. ;-) This is the one thing our government does mostly well. It is a good resource.

Comment: BTW- Welcome to this site. You just got your first up-vote. How does it feel?

Comment: It feels great, thanks! I use the World Factbook for research quite often, so I thought it would be a good resource for looking up commonly spoken languages in that region.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I bought one each year the first few years it came out before it was on the Internet and found it very helpful in some of the research I was doing. Unlike many government resources, it was up to date! Back then, you were researching with data anywhere fro 4 to 10 years old. But the World Factbook was updated each year with new and accurate information. I loved it! I have not needed to use it for a long time now, but I am glad you mentioned it. BTW- I know it is slow now, but you will find some real experts here on this site. I just hope that it works for you.